# how to create a number with a variable number of zeros as first in SAS

Tags: sas

I have to `merge` two dataset in `SAS` where in one the key variable is a number where the lentgh is 10 (for example). If the number is shorter than 10 I have a variable number of zeros. For example `00000056471`.
While in the other dataset the number is simply `56471`. I want to create another variable in the second dataset that add the variable number of zero and use that as key variable for the `merge`.

How can I fix?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches you could use:

```
data have;
input ID $10. ;
cards;
143134
12
14356677
12f
oh dear
;run;

data want;
  set have;
  /* if numeric then convert to number and back using z10 format */
  newID=put(input(ID,8.),$z10.);
  /* if alphanumeric, right align then replace spaces (will replace ALL spaces) */
  newID2=translate(right(ID),'0',' '); 
  /* probably the best method */
  newID3=repeat('0',10-length(ID)-1)||ID;
run;
```

Documentation on Zw.d format available [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000205244.htm).

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that this variables is character and it have to remain character because in the other dataset the variable is character (there is also alphanumeric values).